# A piece of software/cli for Mac OS to see how long a key is pressed?

Tags: keyboard, timer, keyboard-listener, keylogger

I'm currently working on the firmware for my keyboard, which is using [QMK](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware).

One of the features of qmk is that you can program your keys to do one thing when pressed and another thing when held. E.g. when pressing and releasing Caps Lock, it will function as Escape, but when pressed and held it will function as Ctrl.

To distinguish between a hold and a press, QMK uses a timer. I'm currently fiddling a lot with changing the timer, compiling and flashing the keyboard, which can be cumbersome.

**So, I was wondering if there is a piece of software (or cli tool) for Mac OS (Ventura 13.5 to be exact) that will show me how long a key has been held in milliseconds before being released again?**

I've been looking through whatever I could find, but my searches only came up with solutions for monitoring keypress, but not with timers.

(I'ved tagged this with `keylogger` as I thought there might be a keylogger with this functionality?)